# mysql keep subquery out of a join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I want to count the percentage of (pid = pid_raw) out of the total number of pid_raw where date_raw is 31 days before the date.

I know i can do it partly with an inner join but because i want to get the percentage and thus need the total count of pid_raw regardless of match, that sub-query cant be part of the inner join. How can i write my subquery to get total count of pid_raw that is not affected by the inner join but in line with the where clause?

```
table1
date          pid
2015-06-01    223
2015-06-01    333 
2015-05-01    124 
2015-05-01    543 


table2
date_raw      pid_raw
2015-05-30    223
2015-05-15    111
2015-05-03    333 
2015-05-02    242
2015-05-05    300
2015-04-10    124
2015-04-15    543
2015-04-09    511


Example output
date         pid_percentage
2015-06-01     0.40           <-------(2/5)
2015-05-01     0.67            <------(2/3)
```

My sudo code:

```
select count(a.pid)/(select count(b.pid_raw) from b) AS pid_percentage, a.date       from 
table1 a join table2 b
ON a.pid = b.pid_raw
Where a.date - b.date_raw <=31 and a.date - b.date_raw > 0
group by a.date
order by YEAR(a.date),Month(a.date);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to join on the dates and then use conditional aggregation for the calculation:

```
select t1.date,
       count(distinct case when t1.pid = t2.pid_raw then t1.pid end) as NumMatches,
       (count(distinct case when t1.pid = t2.pid_raw then t1.pid end) / 
        count(distinct case when t1.pid = t2.pid_raw then t2.pid_raw end) 
       ) as percentage_pid
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t2.date_raw between t1.date - interval 31 day and t1.date
group by t1.date;
```

Comment: thanks although this runs, it takes too long and times out before i get any output. is there a better way to do it?